# GroupBy, Agreggate Strings and return unique values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

## How to add a new column of aggregated data

I want to create 03 new columns in a dataframe

###### Column 01: unique_list

> Create a new column in the dataframe of unique values of `cfop_code` for each `key`

###### Column 02: unique_count

> A column that check the number of unique values that shows in unique_list

###### Column 03: not_unique_count

> A column that check the number of not unique values that shows in unique_list

### example_df

|  | key | product | cfop_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345678901234567890 | product a | 2551 |
| 1 | 12345678901234567890 | product b | 2551 |
| 2 | 12345678901234567890 | product c | 3551 |
| 3 | 12345678901234567895 | product a | 2551 |
| 4 | 12345678901234567897 | product b | 2551 |
| 5 | 12345678901234567897 | product c | 2407 |

#### Expected Result

|  | key | product | cfop_code | unique_list | unique_count | not_unique_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345678901234567890 | product a | 2551 | 2251, 3551 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 12345678901234567890 | product b | 2551 | 2251, 3551 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 12345678901234567890 | product c | 3551 | 2251, 3551 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 12345678901234567895 | product a | 2551 | 2251 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 12345678901234567897 | product b | 2551 | 2407, 2551 | 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 12345678901234567897 | product c | 2407 | 2407, 2551 | 2 | 2 |

---

### What i had tried

##### Create a list of unique values

```py
df.groupby('key')["cfop"].unique()

key
12345678901234567890    [2551, 3551]
12345678901234567895          [2551]
12345678901234567897    [2551, 2407]
Name: cfop, dtype: object
```

##### Getting the count not unique values

```py
df.groupby("key").agg(**{"unique_values": pd.NamedAgg(column='cfop', aggfunc="size")}).reset_index()

key unique_values
0   12345678901234567890    3
1   12345678901234567895    1
2   12345678901234567897    2
```

##### Getting the count unique values into data frame

```py
df.groupby("key").agg(**{"unique_values": pd.NamedAgg(column='cfop', aggfunc="nunique")}).reset_index()

key unique_values
0   12345678901234567890    2
1   12345678901234567895    1
2   12345678901234567897    2
```

### But FAIL adding a new column

```py
df['unique_list'] = df.groupby('key')["cfop"].unique()
```

```py
df['unique_count'] = df.groupby("key").agg(**{"unique_values": pd.NamedAgg(column='cfop', aggfunc="nunique")}).reset_index()
df['not_unique_count'] =df.groupby("key").agg(**{"unique_values": pd.NamedAgg(column='cfop', aggfunc="size")}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tmp = (
    df.groupby("key")["cfop_code"]
    .agg(
        unique_list = lambda s: sorted(s.unique()), 
        unique_count = "nunique", 
        not_unique_count = "size")
    .reset_index()
)
res = df.merge(tmp, on="key")

print(res)
                    key    product  cfop_code   unique_list  unique_count  not_unique_count
0  12345678901234567890  product a       2551  [2551, 3551]             2                 3
1  12345678901234567890  product b       2551  [2551, 3551]             2                 3
2  12345678901234567890  product c       3551  [2551, 3551]             2                 3
3  12345678901234567895  product a       2551        [2551]             1                 1
4  12345678901234567897  product b       2551  [2407, 2551]             2                 2
5  12345678901234567897  product c       2407  [2407, 2551]             2                 2
```

The problem with your attempt is that:

```
df.groupby("key").agg(**{"unique_values": pd.NamedAgg(column='cfop_code', aggfunc="nunique")}).reset_index()
```

returns a DataFrame.You try to assign this whole DataFrame to a new column which fails.

Comment: the merge solution works fine!  Thanks so very Much!

Comment: Rabinzel is it possible to unique_list shows sorted result A-Z???

Comment: updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do merge after group and agg like:

```
df.merge(df.groupby('key',as_index=False).agg(
   unique_list = ('cfop_code', 'unique'),
   unique_count = ('cfop_code', 'nunique'),
   not_unique_count = ('cfop_code', 'size')
), on='key', how = 'left')
```

output:

```
                    key    product  cfop_code   unique_list  unique_count  \
0  12345678901234567890  product a       2551  [2551, 3551]             2   
1  12345678901234567890  product b       2551  [2551, 3551]             2   
2  12345678901234567890  product c       3551  [2551, 3551]             2   
3  12345678901234567895  product a       2551        [2551]             1   
4  12345678901234567897  product b       2551  [2551, 2407]             2   
5  12345678901234567897  product c       2407  [2551, 2407]             2   

   not_unique_count  
0                 3  
1                 3  
2                 3  
3                 1  
4                 2  
5                 2
```

Comment: It seems more clear for me!  Thanks so much!

Comment: SomeDude is it possible to unique_list shows sorted result A-Z???

Comment: @AndreNevares yes, you can do : `df['unique_list'] = df['unique_list'].apply(lambda x:sorted(x))`

Comment: is it possible to remove the brackets from the String.    So it shows ```2551, 3551``` instead of ```[2551, 3551]``` ... Many thanks on advance

Comment: Yes, `df['unique_list'] = df['unique_list'].apply(','.join)`

Comment: do not work.   My humble and newbee solution was ```res['unique_list'] = res['unique_list'].astype('string').str.replace("[","").str.replace("]","")```... it works.  But is not pythonic ;)